# Xml serialization appending the \0 (backslash 0 or Null) character?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an object and the \0 (Null) character is being appended to the generated string.  Why?

My code:

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Common.PlanogramSearchOptions));
 MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
 serializer.Serialize(memStream, searchOptions);

 string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer()); // appends \0
```

My work around is replacing the Null character with an empty string

```
xml.Replace("\0", string.Empty)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[MemoryStream.GetBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) returns the underlying buffer of the [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a84386f.aspx) (which is larger than the actual data stored in it). You want [MemoryStream.ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx).

However, I recommend you use a [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) instead of [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a84386f.aspx), so you can avoid the UTF-8 conversion:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlanogramSearchOptions));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(writer, searchOptions);
string xml = writer.ToString();
```

See also: [Serialize an object to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434534/serialize-an-object-to-string/2434558#2434558)

Comment: Excellent! That worked and thank you for your suggestion... i will implement that across the board.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I was using MemoryStream.GetBuffer when I meant ToArray in a different context. Found my way here eventually. :)