# Dynamics CRM Plugin Shared variables - Object or Array

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

We have a scenario where we need to calculate multiple fee components & share between Pre & Post stages of a Plugin. So we created the object like this.

```
class FeeCalculation
    {
        public string TotalFee { get; set; }
        public string FilingFee { get; set; }
        public string LegalFee { get; set; }
        public string RecordFee { get; set; }
    }
```

So far we have used single fee component & shared variable worked nicely. When tried to assign the whole object - the result is not fruitful.

```
context.SharedVariables.Add("fees", fcObject);
```

Is there a way to achieve this expected result?

Comment: uhm, long time that I don't use shared variables, but if you serialize your object to XML, pass as a string, and deserialize, it should work

Comment: Exactly I thought the same to do serialize/deserialize. You confirmed it, will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin infrastructure must be able to serialize/deserialize the objects that are in your `SharedVariables` collection. It has no knowledge of custom types like the `FeeCalculation` class and therefore cannot serialize it.

Use primitive types, common .NET types (e.g. a `List` of decimals should work) or CRM types (`Entity`, `Money` etc.). It's good to note that the `SharedVariables` collection is a key value pair collection. So, why not just add items to it with keys like "TotalFee", "FilingFee" etc?

Comment: Yes I agree, but not all the fee components will be applicable all the time. Will try & let you know.. thanks.

Comment: @ArunVinoth as a possible alternative you can manually serialize/deserialize and pass serialized string as a shared variable.

Comment: @AndriiButenko - Worked great thank you and a better answer IMHO.  Used these extension methods https://stackoverflow.com/a/26026980

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to share an `IEnumerable<Guid>`, but collections like `List` did not work.

Of course you can always serialize to string, but your plugin code really shouldn't have to deal with serialization of common types.

After some trial and error, I ended up using arrays, i.e. `Guid[]`.