# Convert C# class property into XML attribute

Tags: c#, .net, linq, json.net

I am trying to convert properties of a C# class into XML attribute.

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string c { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string r { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string p { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string v { get; set; }
    }

MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.c = "1";
obj.r = "2";
obj.p = "3";
obj.v = "4";
```

Now converting class into XML using newton soft:

```
            dynamic obj2 = new ExpandoObject();
            obj2.data = obj;
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj2);
            XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "root");
```

produces something like this:

```
<root>
  <data>
    <c>1</c>
    <r>2</r>
    <p>3</p>
    <v>4</v>
  </data>
 </root>
```

**But I want something like this:**

```
  <root>
      <data c="1" r="2" p="3" v="4" />
     </root>
```

I want to convert properties into attributes, not elements.

When I use XML Serializer, I want a string out and don't want to write data to a file or stream.

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
```

Comment: Use XmlSerializer and decorate the properties with the appropriate attributes like XmlElement / XmlAttribute / XmlArray / XmlRoot / etc.

Comment: Why are you using a JSON library to serialize something to XML?

Comment: @HereticMonkey : I found it easy to work with. And it worked well when I was converting properties into elements. Does not work when I want to convert properties into attribute.

Comment: @Igor: i tried it. `Serialize` function does not have a return type.

Comment: Because it serializes the instance to a stream or writer of your choice. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @OpenStack Igor's suggestion is how I would go about this too.  Using Newtonsoft for this is, well, odd.  Can you show us how you tried implementing Igor's suggestion?  `XmlSerializer` gives you a tremendous amount of control over how your model is serialized.

Comment: @Amy Updated the question.

Comment: @OpenStack ... After reading my comment back to myself, I want to clarify: I do not mean to suggest that you *cannot* get this to work as expected using Newtonsoft.  We can *probably* help with that.  But because the usual process is to use `XmlSerializer`, that's what we know best, so we want to steer you in that direction.  Personally, I do not remember ever using Newtonsoft to produce XML, so I would need to experiment to find a solution, if there is a solution.  I hope this makes sense.  That said, the code you added makes perfect sense, and we can *definitely* help with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize an object to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434534/serialize-an-object-to-string)

Comment: @Igor Thank you for quick help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize an object to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434534/serialize-an-object-to-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete solution.  I recommend wrapping the writer in a `using`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.c = "1";
        obj.r = "2";
        obj.p = "3";
        obj.v = "4";

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        string result;
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
            result = writer.ToString();
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @Igor, this is what I did and it worked

```
       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        var xml = writer.ToString();
```