# is there an easy way to parse a class into a string in both directions

Tags: c#, string, class

Suppose I have a simple class like that:

```
public class Person {
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public Gender gender; //enum type

    //constructor
}
```

Is there a built-in way to parse an object of this class to a string and then, back to `Person`?

I probably will implement a `ToString()` myself but I'd like to know if there is something already made for this.

The string doesn't need to be comprehensible, as long as it is invertible.

---

**Example**

```
Person p = new Person("Bob", 12, Gender.Male);
string s = Stringify(p);   //s = "Bob#12#Male"
Person c = Personify(s);   //c is just like Bob
```

Comment: you can serialize an object into json string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Comment: You can use xml as well...

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434534/serialize-an-object-to-string) has different examples that work along with many others here on SO, choose one to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use many sorts of serialization to achieve this, one simple approach would be to use [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

**Example**

```
var funkyString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<person>(funkyString);
```

<sub>***Note** : If in .NET Core 3.x, you no longer need `Json.net`. There is now a [Json serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=netcore-3.1) in the framework. – [insane_developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14019150/insane-developer)*</sub>

If you want more control over what the string looks like, one approach would be to override `ToString()` in your class, and write a custom decoder to unencode your data and set your properties (this would be easy to get wrong for more complex types).

Comment: If in .NET Core 3.x, you no longer need Json.net. There is now a [Json serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=netcore-3.1) in the framework.