# C# to VB.NET conversion XML serializer

Tags: c#, vb.net

I was using

```
Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
```

but then I realized that I need to change the initialization to

```
XmlSerializer s = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(new[] { typeof(CustomXMLSerializeObject) })[0];
```

in order to work around a bug (according to [C# XmlSerializer BindingFailure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209443/c-sharp-xmlserializer-bindingfailure))

However, I am not sure how to get my "T" into it when I try to convert this code to VB.NET.

An online converter told me that the C# code

```
 XmlSerializer s = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(new[] { typeof(CustomXMLSerializeObject) })[0];
```

should be

```
Dim s As XmlSerializer = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(New () {GetType(CustomXMLSerializeObject)})(0)
```

However, this cannot really be correct since the New () raises a compiler error.

Also I am not sure how to add my "T" to it.

Thank you for the help!

My current, faulty code is this:

```
Public Function DeepClone(Of T)(obj As T) As T
    Using ms = New MemoryStream()
        Dim xs As XmlSerializer = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(New () {GetType(CustomXMLSerializeObject)})(0)
        Return DirectCast(xs.Deserialize(ms), T)
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: MSDN Doc. Click VB code example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.fromtypes(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2   I think you just need to say `New Type(){...}` instead of `New (){...}` though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the 'New' at all - just use:

```
Dim s As XmlSerializer = XmlSerializer.FromTypes( { GetType(CustomXMLSerializeObject) })(0)
```

Comment: Oh, and your code does not compile. It says that the type CustomXMLSerializeObject is not defined.

Comment: @tmighty: How does your original C# integrate 'T'?  Did you also want someone to define the CustomXMLSerializeObject type for you?  This doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: The original code does not integrate T, but I would like to know how this could be done.